# Labview DAQ Assistant Error 50103 (Speed control with a DC motor)

Tags: labview

I have been trying to develop a speed control for a small dc motor in both directions but I can't seem to get it working. The speed control works fine if I am using it in one direction only. Here are the scenarios in which it works:

1) I run the program and I rotate my duty cycle knob from (0,100]. The resulting action is speed control clockwise on my motor - perfect

2) I run the program and i rotate my duty cycle knob from [-100,0]. The resulting action is speed control counter clockwise on my motor - perfect.

The problem arises when I transition from CCW to CW or CW to CCW:

3) I run the program in the (0,100] domain, however, the minute I transition into the [-100,0) domain, i get the error included in my picture and it highlights the DAQ Assistant - not good.

The DAQ Assistant is configured to output to AO(0) when true and to output to AO(1) when false. Lastly, both DAQ assistant have been configured for continuous sampling.

Lastly, I am also using a motor driver to interface with my motor. Any ideas how I can bypass the 50103 error, I could not figure it out.

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfiJr.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your image, it appears that there is only one analog output timing engine on whichever DAQ device you're using. I'm also assuming there is a second DAQ Assistant block in True case to handle positive duty cycles.

You are receiving the error because the first DAQ Assistant that runs is keeping the AO hardware resources reserved so that when the second DAQ Assistant attempts to control the hardware, it can't.

The fix is to always use both channels and only use one DAQ Assistant. When generating data, fill the 'active' channel with the control signal and the 'inactive' channel with 0s.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add a bit more detail and tips to what Joe already mentioned. There is more detail on this error in [KnowledgeBase4T6CQKBP: Causes of NI-DAQmx Error -50103 "The Specified Resource is Reserved"](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/485201B647950BF886257537006CEB89) under Case 4:

> Using multiple DAQ Assistant Express VIs to access channels on the
>   same data acquisition board can cause this error because each Express
>   VI creates a separate task.  It is not possible to have multiple DAQmx
>   tasks attempting to access the same physical device. Thus it is
>   necessary to clear each task after the data acquisition has completed.
>   The stop input of the DAQ Assistant Express VI stops the task and
>   releases device resources when the Express VI completes execution.

It is common to run into development limitation like this with DAQ Assistant Express VIs. You should consider transitioning to a task based solution (which is what the Express VI implements behind the scenes). To get started with this you can actually convert your DAQ Assistant Express VI into task based code by doing,

1. Right-click DAQ Assistant Express VI
2. Select "Generate NI-DAQmx Code"